# Error 400 while trying to do a Post request

Tags: java, http, http-post

I'm trying to make a post request in Java, but it's returning the 400 error.

The code:

```
        String urlParameters  = "UserName=xxxx&ApplicationId=xx";
        byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        int    postDataLength = postData.length;
        String request        = "http://url/";
        URL    url            = new URL( request );
        HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
        conn.setDoOutput( true );
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
        conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        conn.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "runscope/0.1");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Accept", "*/*");
        System.out.println(Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
        conn.setUseCaches( false );
        try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
           wr.write( postData );
        }

        System.out.println(conn.getContent().toString());
```

The Stack Trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: url
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at rest.Aplicacao.main(Aplicacao.java:42)
```

Comment: Status code 400 means bad request. Your request is malformed. Check with your site what kind of request they are expecting.

Comment: The URL and the parameter are right. Actually, I've tried here (www.hurl.it) and everything works correctly.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes gives one description of the response codes, I either refer to it on the "HttpCodes" class of the http client library I am using. Still never seen a 418 in the wild though ;)

Comment: If you used your basic browser functionality to try this request and it worked, its because it probably performed a GET request, not a POST.

Comment: No, I set POST request in www.hurl.it. If I try with GET request i get this: '"Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."'

Comment: FYI, `Charset` is not really a header. The closest were `Accept-Charset`. If you want to specify the charset of your payload, you usually do so through the `Content-Type` header like so: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. I'm really, really unsure if this is valid with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.